# Linking.canOpenURL returning false on expo React-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a React-Native built with expo;

When i run in localhost, it works.
But when i upload the build to expo, download the apk and install in a physical device, supported returns false.

Note: When i test it with the url 'https://google.com' it works on both localhost and apk build

```
 const url2 = `https://wa.me/${whatsappNumber}?text=${whatsappMessage}`    

        Linking.canOpenURL(url2)
            .then((supported) => {
                if (supported) {
                    return Linking.openURL(url2);
                } else {
                    Alert.alert('error here')
                    //console.log("WhatsApp is not installed on the device.");
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert(`error catch ${error}`)
            });
```

Comment: Make sure that phone number not include + at the beginning

Comment: `whatsappMessage` must be encoded to URL valid characters - ,https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Link to the specification: https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934.